# Calculate the distance between a single point and multiple polygons using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, distance, st-distance, closest-distance

I’m working with a very large dataset and I need to calculate the shortest distance between a single point and the closest edge from multiple polygons. I need to use PostGIS because such a task with a take a very long time in QGIS or GRASS GIS.

Unfortunately, I’m relatively new to PostGIS. I’ve been googling and found a QGIS plugin that has code for doing similar tasks in PostGIS (https://github.com/NaturalGIS/naturalgis_postgis_geoprocessing). Based on its “minimum distance” algorithm, I wrote the following query that unfortunately does not work:

My schema is called "sar", the point is a vector called "point" and the polygons are in a vector called "rep".

```
CREATE TABLE sar.distances; 
WITH sar.distances AS (SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom FROM sar.rep_ex) 
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(g1.geom,g2.geom)::geometry(LINESTRING,3857) AS geom, ST_Distance(g1.geom,g2.geom) AS distance, g1.id AS id from 
FROM sar.point_ex AS g1, sar.distances AS g2
```

The error is message is:

```
[ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE sar.distances;  WITH sar.distances AS (SELECT S...
                                  ^
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm attaching a small sample of the data I'm working with (point_ex.shp and rep_ex.shp).

https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/example_data_zip/21836508

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the first two errors you pointed out. As for the ST_Union(geom), I have no idea. I just copy pasted the code from the source I mentioned, made some changes and hoped for the best.

Comment: In the example dataset, 1 point and ~ 400 polygons.

Comment: @BERA Minimum distance between a single point (just one thankfully) and all polygons. In the original dataset, the number of polygons can be as high as 2000.

Comment: @Babel I get this error message: [ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE sar.distances;      WITH sar.distances AS (SELE...
                                  ^
]

Comment: Based on your question, the use of ST_Union() is not required, perhaps you would need to replace it with ST_Dump(), although...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [cross join](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cross-join/) all points to all polygons to measure distances and create shortest lines:

```
select  pnt.id as pointid, 
        poly.id as polyid,
        st_distance(pnt.geom, poly.geom) as distance, 
        st_shortestline(pnt.geom, poly.geom) as geom
from public.pointtable pnt
cross join public.polygontable poly
```

There's a line from each point to all polygons, 2581*65=167765 lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine to try QGIS expressions, you can use this expression to create the lines:

```
with_variable (
    'point',
    geometry (
        get_feature_by_id(
            'point_ex',
            1
        )
    ),
    make_line (
        @point,
        closest_point (
            $geometry,
            @point
        )
    )
)
```

If you want to calculate the length of these lines, add a `length()` function: enclose the whole expression from above as argument in the function: `length ( [expression_from_above] )` and you get the length of the lines.

*Red lines created by the expression above:*
[image]

*Calculating the length of the lines with Field Calculator:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's very useful for visual inspection, but in this case I need to measure the distances between the point and the polygons.

Comment: No problem. Simply add a `length()` function to calculate the length of the red lines. Enclose the expression from above as argument in the function: `length ( [expression_from_above] )` and you're done

Comment: @Babel, it is about PostGIS ^_^

Comment: Yes, that's why i added "If you are fine to try QGIS expressions" and OP states that they use QGIS - so they might feel free to try different ways to achieve the goal

Comment: No complaints on having more than one solution for the problem. I added length() to the expression, but where can I see the lengths of the lines? Is there a table?

Comment: Use Field calculator on the polygon layer and the expression will create a new attribute field with the lengths. Define a field name and field type first, then insert the expression (you get a preview at the bottom) - see screenshot at the bottom of my updated answer.